# Unload SplashScreen Image

Tags: vb.net

I have an application that loads a spashscreen which loads a picture and centers this for a set length of time.

The issue I have is that the file used by splashscreen is locked and I can not make any modifications or replace it etc. until application is unloaded.

I am using the default VB net Spashscreen method and the code I use for the image is below

```
Dim Advert As System.Drawing.Image = Image.FromFile("Y:\Test\TestPic.jpg")
Dim width As Integer = Advert.Width
Dim height As Integer = Advert.Height
Me.BackgroundImage = Advert
Me.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch
Me.Size = New Size(width, height)
Me.CenterToScreen()
```

and then this code in the application events to overide the display time

```
Protected Overrides Function OnInitialize(ByVal commandLineArgs As 
           System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection(Of String)) As Boolean

    Me.MinimumSplashScreenDisplayTime = 7000
    Return MyBase.OnInitialize(commandLineArgs)
End Function
```

Is there a way to release the image file when the splash screen closes.

Comment: All you gotta do is `Dispose` the object `Advert`. or better use [Using](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement)

Comment: Why do you load the image from file?  Does it change periodically like an advertisement?

Comment: Yes its an advert that changes, where would I dispose the object Advert, the splash screen does not have an unload event, or how would I implement Using in this scenario, still a novice

Comment: Use `Advert.Dispose` after you have shown the splash screen to free the file

Comment: The splashscreen is a form and all forms have a closing event.  You can also use the ImageLocation property rather than `Image.FromFile` and not have to fret about anything

Comment: Appreciate the help so far but I cannot find an event that fires when it closes

formclosing doesn't fire, have been informed this is a known fault

Note The splash form is set as the Applications splash screen

Comment: I have made a workaround  solution, not very good but appears to work, I have made the Advert a public Var in a module and then when the form after the splashscreen is fully loaded it disposes of the Advert, as said this is a workaround there must be a better solution then this but I cant find it, if someone could make an example  that would be great.